# Soccer score prediction using brain.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neural-network

I want to train brain.js app using previous match scores. For example

```
team1 2-3 team2
team2 2-0 team1
team3 2-1 team2
...
```

If i predict score between two teams, output looks like [0.863456362846, 0.01231223112312].
What should I do to get real score prediction that looks like [2,3]?

Comment: I'd say that with only those factors (it's a ratio, isn't it?) it's not possible. You could do something like predict the score of one of them and then get the other score based on the first score and the ratio. I hope I've explained myself clear enough.

Comment: If i get one of scores it will be between 0 and 1. how can I get factor to multiply by output?

Comment: You could do a prediction only for the result of Team A against Team B, based on the results of previous matches A against B. (Probability of A scoring 0 against B, A scoring 1 against B...).
Once you've got that predicted score, you can apply the ratio upon it to predict the score of Team B.

If you have a predicted score of 2 for Team A, and an output [0.67, 0,33], you'd end up having [2,1] for A against B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can train a network to predict outputs like `{score0: 0, score1: 0, score2: 1, ..., score7: 0}` for inputs like `{team1: 'team', team2: 'team2'}`. Which means team1 scored 2 times. Then run it for 2 inputs `{team1: 'team1', team2: 'team2'}` and `{team1: 'team2', team2: 'team1'}` to predict both scores each time taking the most probable output.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to use a non-linear function (perhaps like Log) to translate the training outputs to the human-readable estimates and vice versa.

Sports like Soccer generally produce a lot of low scoring games, so generally a lot of figures range between the 0-2 mark.  These can be occasions however where the scores can be much higher, but cases are far fewer.  To discourage the NN from always guessing low, the distribution would need to somehow be evened out to maximise learning ability.

In this way, the training may be more effective and the results can be translated to something human-readable once cases have been evaluated by the Neural Network.

Answer (score 0):

Use brain.recurrent.RNN ()

It takes non-floating outputs.
Read the brain.js docs.